# Can I use negations in the rules of inference?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

For example, modus ponens is $p \land (p → q) \therefore q$.

If I had $¬p$ and $¬q$, could I do $¬p \land (¬p → ¬q) \therefore ¬q$?

Comment: Yes, just as if you could do with *any* wff substituted for $p,q$, maybe even  $(a^2+b^2=c^2)\land (a^2+b^2=c^2\to \gamma=90^\circ)\therefore \gamma=90^\circ$

Comment: sure ... relabel, $y = ¬p,\ z = ¬q$, and the statement holds for $y,\ z$... just do the substitution

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Your comment should be an answer. =)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, modus ponens does not have a conjunction in the antecedent.  It has two premises, not one.

Answer (score 0):

No, modus ponens is not a conjunction.  A conjunction consists of a single proposition.  Modus ponens has two premises. Also, modus ponens works for implicational propositional calculi where no conjunctions exist.

You can substitute a negated formula into an inference rule and obtain a derivable rule of inference provided that you substitute the negated formula uniformly for the formula you substitute for.  In other words, if you substitute $\alpha$ with $\lnot$p, then wherever $\alpha$ appears in the formula you have to substitute it with $\lnot$p.  Your example would then consist of something like {$\lnot$p, ($\lnot$p $\rightarrow$ $\lnot$q)} $\vdash$ $\lnot$q, where $\lnot$p and ($\lnot$p $\rightarrow$ $\lnot$q) consist of distinct premises.